# Why does relative difference granger cause log difference? (time series)

Tags: time-series, python, granger-causality

I've been running Granger causality tests on stationary time series in Python. Testing the same time series with itself gives me p-values of 1 for all tests (i.e. no causality), except for the parameter F test, which returns `p = 0`.

However, when testing the relative change of a time series against the log change of the same time series (which obviously also doesn't have a causal relationship), I get p-values of 0 for all four tests, in either direction.

For small variances on the other hand, I get large discrepancies between the test's p-values.

My questions are:

- Why does the parameter F test return a p-value of zero for two identical time series?
- Why do all Granger causality tests indicate a bidirectional causal relationship between relative difference and log difference?
- Why are there so large discrepancies between the p-values of the various tests when the variance is small?

To reproduce the result where all p-values are zero, run:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import grangercausalitytests

time_series = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 2, 100))
time_series_relative_change = (time_series / time_series.shift(1) - 1)[1:]
time_series_log_difference = np.log(time_series / time_series.shift(1))[1:]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe['time_series_relative_change'] = time_series_relative_change
dataframe['time_series_log_difference'] = time_series_log_difference
grangercausalitytests(dataframe, 10)
```

To reproduce the result where the discrepancy between test results is large, run:

```
time_series = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10, 0.1, 100))
time_series_relative_change = (time_series / time_series.shift(1) - 1)[1:]
time_series_log_difference = np.log(time_series / time_series.shift(1))[1:]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe['time_series_relative_change'] = time_series_relative_change
dataframe['time_series_log_difference'] = time_series_log_difference
grangercausalitytests(dataframe, 10)
```